# Using pthread_mutex in a mutli threaded programme

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, thread-synchronization

I am working on a code which creates three thread . Now using pthread_mutex how can  i synchronize them?
Lets say i have this type of code:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>

void *function1(void *ptr)
{

   do something on a buffer;
}

void *function2(void *ptr)
{
  do samething else but ob the same buffer;
 }

void *function(void *ptr)
{
  do samething else again on buffer;
}


main()
{ 
   pthread_t t1,t2,t3);
   int a,b,c;
   a= creates a thread using pthread_create(&t1,NULL,func1,NULL);
   b= creates a thread using pthread_create(&t2,NULL,func2,NULL);
   c= creates a thread using pthread_create(&t3,NULL,func1,NULL);

 and after that pthread_join wait till all the threads gets finished;
}
```

But as you can see when you do such thing all threads starts simultaneously and the result is not as expected . Now how can we use pthread_mutex to lock and unlock the same buffer so that at a time only one thread can work on it?
Also i want t1 to come first then t2 and after that t3. How can it be done basically i have to set priority ?

Comment: Something tells me that if opened *any* manual or looked for examples on the internet you would have found thousands of code examples and explanations for this...

Comment: As @KerrekSB said, first search for answers, then ask question. Your question is pretty basic, you will find its answer even if you read the usage of pthread mtexes.

Comment: I read about pthread_mutex_lock() but when i implement the output is not as expexted. I want to call t1 then t2 and then t3 but when i compile the code the order is random . How can i getrid of this?

Answer (score 2):

See this example: http://sourcecookbook.com/en/recipes/70/basic-and-easy-pthread-mutex-lock-example-c-thread-synchronization

You must do a little bit of reading, but it's pretty easy.
You must declare and initialize the mutex:
pthread_mutex_t myMutex;
pthread_mutex_init(&myMutex, NULL);

and to use it:

pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);

// use the buffer here

pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);

Also don't forget to cleanup:
pthread_mutex_destroy(&myMutex);

Comment: I read about pthread_mutex_lock() but when i implement the output is not as expexted. I want to call t1 then t2 and then t3 but when i compile the code the order is random . How can i getrid of this?

Comment: @user2714823 You can't. Threads execute whenever they can, which is, as you say, random.

Comment: in the above example i want first thread1 finishes then thread2 and thread3 . Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you need threads then? You can just call the methods. If, however, you still want to call the threads in a sequential manner(lets say for experimental reasons) you can use pthread_join to wait for thread termination. Basically you start t1, then you wait for it with pthread_join. Then you start t2 and use pthread_join again etc.